# Can a "WebPage" be a part of "SoftwareApplication" in schema json?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

So what I mean is can I have it like this?

```js
{
"@type": "WebPage",
"isPartOf": {
  "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
  }
}
```

Or it can only be a part of a WebSite?

Comment: At the very least, if you test on the Structured Data Testing tool it will validate fine.

Comment: Yes. Under https://schema.org/WebPage you find `isPartOf` property.